# Faster insert into SQL Server where table has constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm inserting millions of rows of data into a SQL Server table. As part of the procedure, the table is created using the following rules:

```
CONSTRAINT [constraint1] 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC, [other_id] ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
```

Once the table is created, the large insert job inserts rows as follows:

```
INSERT INTO tableName 
    SELECT 
        [id], [other_id]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[source_table];
```

Is there any way to improve the performance of the inserts, given I need to keep the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON` condition due to data quality issues at source (i.e. duplicate keys)?

Comment: If you need to do these operations as written (create, constrain, & insert), it would be best to hold off on the constraints/indexes until after the INSERT is completed. you can use the `ALTER TABLE` method. I myself would create a new column so my PK is not duplicated.

Comment: right, so i can just switch on the constraint after the data is loaded... my only concern with this is how any duplicates would be handled once the key is applied - my only requirement is that the procedure doesn't fail but quietly ignores any duplicate keys

Comment: What's the purpose of the constraint? Do you ever need to enforce uniqueness? It seems like you should create a clustered index, _not_ a primary key.

Comment: there is a risk of duplicates in the source table (which are out of my control), so the constraint is to ensure duplicates are ignored, and to provide the ascending order to the keys

Comment: You could also "chunk" the insert by inserting `id` 1-100,000 then 100,001-200,000 etc... to avoid large transaction log (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server) usage which is also contributing to the run-time/performance issue you're experiencing. If that doesn't work you could look into partition swapping methods too (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use SELECT DISTINCT against your source table?

Comment: Adding onto what @JohnMo commented, add a second table with  a PK-FK reference and populate that with the duplicates

Comment: @JohnMo SELECT DISTINCT could work, would it be faster than the current approach?

Comment: I know the load will go faster if you remove the primary key constraint on the target table. The time required to load + build the index will _likely_ be less than the time to load the table with the index in place. A clustered index is going to be slow to build because the data has to be physically rearranged. Why do you feel like you need a clustered index?

Comment: Just a clustered index (not a primary key with IGNORE_DUP_KEY ON) will apply order without falsely implying it's a primary key. Not having a primary key is a bad thing. You should take steps to clean your data

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid agreed, unfortunately I have no control over the source data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the indexing to do the the table load.

Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to enforce uniqueness.

Reconsider your indexing. Applying a clustered index is going to be slow because the data has to be physically rearranged for a clustered index. You might consider adding an `IDENTITY` column and making it the PK and then also using a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the id and other_id columns, although a nonclustered PK on id and other_id would accomplish the same thing without the additional column. It depends on what your ongoing use of the data will be.